# JVM issues keeps crashing

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using IntellJ IDEA 13 CE and jdk 1.7.

Compiling my project results in no errors. When I try to run the application, I'm notified that:

`The last time you opened java, it unexpectedly quit while reopening windows. Do you want to try to reopen its windows again?`

Given options reopen/don't reopen, both lead to this error log, and I'm frightened. I've tried reinstalling all my jdk's and intellij:

```
  #
  # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
  #
  #  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000109d00633, pid=15131, tid=6403
  #
  # JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
  # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode bsd-amd64 compressed oops)
  # Problematic frame:
  # V  [libjvm.dylib+0x300633]
  #
  # Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
  #
  # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
  #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
  #

  ---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

  Current thread (0x00007fb353000000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=6403, stack(0x000000010a460000,0x000000010a560000)]

  siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000009

  Registers:
  RAX=0x00000006fb043f00, RBX=0x00007fb352b00d50, RCX=0x000000010a20c203, RDX=0x0000000000000001
  RSP=0x000000010a55e0e0, RBP=0x000000010a55e100, RSI=0x000000010a179830, RDI=0x00000007aaaefba8
  R8 =0x0000000000000320, R9 =0x0000000000000258, R10=0x00007fb350c05330, R11=0x00007fff7744ddb8
  R12=0x00007fb3530001e8, R13=0x000000010a55e208, R14=0x00000007aaaad2f8, R15=0x00007fb3530001e8
  RIP=0x0000000109d00633, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, ERR=0x0000000000000004
    TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

  Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000010a55e0e0)
  0x000000010a55e0e0:   00007fb353000000 00000007aaaad2f8
  0x000000010a55e0f0:   00007fb3530001e8 00007fb353000000
  0x000000010a55e100:   000000010a55e130 0000000109d0d91e
  0x000000010a55e110:   000000010a55e130 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e120:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e130:   000000010a55e1c0 000000012014722b
  0x000000010a55e140:   000000010a55e198 000000900a55e290
  0x000000010a55e150:   0000032000000258 0000014000000096
  0x000000010a55e160:   000000010a55e2d8 00007fb353000000
  0x000000010a55e170:   000000010a55e1b0 0000000109cd555f
  0x000000010a55e180:   00007fb353000000 000000010a55e200
  0x000000010a55e190:   00007fb353000000 00000006fb35f040
  0x000000010a55e1a0:   0000000000000000 00000006fb35f038
  0x000000010a55e1b0:   000000010a55e2d8 00007fb353000000
  0x000000010a55e1c0:   000000010a55e268 000000010a5c2758
  0x000000010a55e1d0:   0000000000000000 0000000100000000
  0x000000010a55e1e0:   0000000100000000 0000000100000000
  0x000000010a55e1f0:   000000010a55e290 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e200:   00000007aaaad2f8 000000010a55e208
  0x000000010a55e210:   00000006fb2a6d4e 000000010a55e258
  0x000000010a55e220:   00000006fb2b3fe8 000000010a55e228
  0x000000010a55e230:   00000006fb35f038 000000010a55e2d8
  0x000000010a55e240:   00000006fb388cb0 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e250:   00000006fb35f040 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e260:   000000010a55e288 000000010a55e328
  0x000000010a55e270:   000000010a5b6233 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e280:   000000010a5becdb 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e290:   00000007ab91a5c8 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e2a0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
  0x000000010a55e2b0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000258
  0x000000010a55e2c0:   0000000000000320 0000000000000096
  0x000000010a55e2d0:   0000000000000140 00000007ab754f58 

  Instructions: (pc=0x0000000109d00633)
  0x0000000109d00613:   c0 75 04 30 c0 eb 39 48 8d 0d ff bb 50 00 80 39
  0x0000000109d00623:   00 49 8b 16 74 15 48 8d 35 00 92 47 00 8a 4e 08
  0x0000000109d00633:   8b 7a 08 48 d3 e7 48 03 3e eb 04 48 8b 7a 08 48
  0x0000000109d00643:   83 c7 10 48 89 c6 e8 2a 90 f3 ff 84 c0 0f 95 c0 

  Register to memory mapping:

  RAX=0x00000006fb043f00 is an oop
  {instance class} 
   - klass: {other class}
  RBX=0x00007fb352b00d50 is a global jni handle
  RCX=0x000000010a20c203: heapOopSize+0x3 in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib at 0x0000000109a00000
  RDX=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
  RSP=0x000000010a55e0e0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb353000000
  RBP=0x000000010a55e100 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb353000000
  RSI=0x000000010a179830: _ZN8Universe11_narrow_oopE+0 in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib at 0x0000000109a00000
  RDI=0x00000007aaaefba8 is an oop
  java.lang.Class 
   - klass: 'java/lang/Class'
  R8 =0x0000000000000320 is an unknown value
  R9 =0x0000000000000258 is an unknown value
  R10=0x00007fb350c05330 is an unknown value
  R11=0x00007fff7744ddb8: OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool+0 in /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation at 0x00007fff8e75b000
  R12=0x00007fb3530001e8 is an unknown value
  R13=0x000000010a55e208 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00007fb353000000
  R14=0x00000007aaaad2f8 is an oop
  java.lang.Boolean 
   - klass: 'java/lang/Boolean'
  R15=0x00007fb3530001e8 is an unknown value


  Stack: [0x000000010a460000,0x000000010a560000],  sp=0x000000010a55e0e0,  free space=1016k
  Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x300633]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x30d91e]
  C  [liblwjgl.jnilib+0xc22b]  Java_org_lwjgl_opengl_MacOSXDisplay_nCreateWindow+0x9b
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.nCreateWindow(IIIIZZZZLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+0
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.createWindow(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/DrawableLWJGL;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/DisplayMode;Ljava/awt/Canvas;II)V+120
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow()V+71
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;)V+72
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+12
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.tryCreateDisplay(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+7
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.access$000(Lorg/newdawn/slick/AppGameContainer;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+2
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+36
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db350]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db120]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x32e8f0]
  j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup()V+112
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start()V+1
  j  pong.Pong.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lserver/PongServer;Lserver/Player;Lserver/Player;)V+206
  j  pong.Pong.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5
  j  pong.Pong.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+6
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db350]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db120]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x465f40]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x4663a6]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x327b83]
  j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
  j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
  j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
  j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
  j  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+163
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db350]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x2db120]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x30e99a]
  V  [libjvm.dylib+0x307b35]
  C  [java+0x30fe]  JavaMain+0x91d
  C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x1899]  _pthread_body+0x8a
  C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x172a]  _pthread_struct_init+0x0
  C  [libsystem_pthread.dylib+0x5fc9]  thread_start+0xd

  Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.nCreateWindow(IIIIZZZZLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;+0
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.MacOSXDisplay.createWindow(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/DrawableLWJGL;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/DisplayMode;Ljava/awt/Canvas;II)V+120
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow()V+71
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/Drawable;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/ContextAttribs;)V+72
  j  org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+12
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.tryCreateDisplay(Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+7
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.access$000(Lorg/newdawn/slick/AppGameContainer;Lorg/lwjgl/opengl/PixelFormat;)V+2
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$2.run()Ljava/lang/Object;+36
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
  j  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedAction;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup()V+112
  j  org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start()V+1
  j  pong.Pong.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lserver/PongServer;Lserver/Player;Lserver/Player;)V+206
  j  pong.Pong.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;)V+5
  j  pong.Pong.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+6
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
  j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
  j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
  j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
  j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+57
  j  com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+163
  v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

  ---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

  Java Threads: ( => current thread )
    0x00007fb352012800 JavaThread "AWT-Shutdown" [_thread_blocked, id=31243, stack(0x000000011c436000,0x000000011c536000)]
    0x00007fb352012000 JavaThread "AppKit Thread" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3335, stack(0x00007fff57297000,0x00007fff57317000)]
    0x00007fb3530bb000 JavaThread "Thread-0" [_thread_in_native, id=22787, stack(0x000000011a3a2000,0x000000011a4a2000)]
    0x00007fb3530b6000 JavaThread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=22275, stack(0x000000011a1c8000,0x000000011a2c8000)]
    0x00007fb351061000 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=21251, stack(0x0000000119dd4000,0x0000000119ed4000)]
    0x00007fb351060000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20739, stack(0x0000000119cd1000,0x0000000119dd1000)]
    0x00007fb35105e800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=20227, stack(0x0000000119bce000,0x0000000119cce000)]
    0x00007fb351059000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=19715, stack(0x0000000119acb000,0x0000000119bcb000)]
    0x00007fb35104e000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14595, stack(0x000000011987a000,0x000000011997a000)]
    0x00007fb35104d800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14083, stack(0x0000000119777000,0x0000000119877000)]
  =>0x00007fb353000000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_vm, id=6403, stack(0x000000010a460000,0x000000010a560000)]

  Other Threads:
    0x00007fb35104b000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000119674000,0x0000000119774000] [id=13571]
    0x00007fb35105a000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000119ed7000,0x0000000119fd7000] [id=21763]

  VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

  VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

  Heap
   PSYoungGen      total 76800K, used 15860K [0x00000007aaa80000, 0x00000007b0000000, 0x0000000800000000)
    eden space 66048K, 24% used [0x00000007aaa80000,0x00000007ab9fd380,0x00000007aeb00000)
    from space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007af580000,0x00000007af580000,0x00000007b0000000)
    to   space 10752K, 0% used [0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007aeb00000,0x00000007af580000)
   ParOldGen       total 174592K, used 0K [0x0000000700000000, 0x000000070aa80000, 0x00000007aaa80000)
    object space 174592K, 0% used [0x0000000700000000,0x0000000700000000,0x000000070aa80000)
   PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 6270K [0x00000006fae00000, 0x00000006fc300000, 0x0000000700000000)
    object space 21504K, 29% used [0x00000006fae00000,0x00000006fb41fa08,0x00000006fc300000)

  Card table byte_map: [0x000000010d670000,0x000000010de9a000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000109e99000

  Polling page: 0x00000001089fd000

  Code Cache  [0x000000010a5b0000, 0x000000010a820000, 0x000000010d5b0000)
   total_blobs=287 nmethods=28 adapters=214 free_code_cache=48651Kb largest_free_block=49795776

  Compilation events (10 events):
  Event: 0.209 Thread 0x00007fb351060000   24             sun.misc.URLClassPath::getResource (74 bytes)
  Event: 0.217 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800 nmethod 20 0x000000010a622190 code [0x000000010a6223a0, 0x000000010a623370]
  Event: 0.217 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800   25   !         sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader::getResource (91 bytes)
  Event: 0.234 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800 nmethod 25 0x000000010a623d10 code [0x000000010a623f60, 0x000000010a624f18]
  Event: 0.234 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800   26             sun.misc.MetaIndex::mayContain (51 bytes)
  Event: 0.237 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800 nmethod 26 0x000000010a61e4d0 code [0x000000010a61e640, 0x000000010a61e8c8]
  Event: 0.292 Thread 0x00007fb351060000 nmethod 24 0x000000010a62b390 code [0x000000010a62b8c0, 0x000000010a62f1d0]
  Event: 1.586 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800   27             java.lang.String::startsWith (7 bytes)
  Event: 1.588 Thread 0x00007fb35105e800 nmethod 27 0x000000010a619e50 code [0x000000010a619fa0, 0x000000010a61a138]
  Event: 1.609 Thread 0x00007fb351060000   28             java.util.Arrays::copyOf (19 bytes)

  GC Heap History (0 events):
  No events

  Deoptimization events (0 events):
  No events

  Internal exceptions (10 events):
  Event: 1.590 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab8c89c0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.590 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab8cced0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.599 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab8fafc8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.599 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab8ff5c0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.600 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab904a80 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.600 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab909f00 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.601 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab911bb0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.602 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab9163b0 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.609 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab91abd8 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244
  Event: 1.609 Thread 0x00007fb353000000 Threw 0x00000007ab920770 at /HUDSON/workspace/7u-2-build-macosx-x86_64/jdk7u60/1081/hotspot/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp:1244

  Events (10 events):
  Event: 1.601 loading class 0x00007fb353885f00
  Event: 1.601 loading class 0x00007fb353885f00 done
  Event: 1.601 loading class 0x00007fb352839840
  Event: 1.601 loading class 0x00007fb352839840 done
  Event: 1.602 loading class 0x00007fb3518bc770
  Event: 1.603 loading class 0x00007fb3518bc770 done
  Event: 1.609 loading class 0x00007fb352b65ef0
  Event: 1.609 loading class 0x00007fb352b65ef0 done
  Event: 1.609 loading class 0x00007fb352839a50
  Event: 1.609 loading class 0x00007fb352839a50 done


  Dynamic libraries:
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Versions/A/Cocoa
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/Security
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/ApplicationServices
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Foundation
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/Versions/A/CoreData
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RemoteViewServices.framework/Versions/A/RemoteViewServices
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/Versions/A/AudioToolbox
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioUnit.framework/Versions/A/AudioUnit
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataDetectorsCore.framework/Versions/A/DataDetectorsCore
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DesktopServicesPriv.framework/Versions/A/DesktopServicesPriv
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIToolbox.framework/Versions/A/HIToolbox
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/Versions/A/QuartzCore
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/SpeechRecognition.framework/Versions/A/SpeechRecognition
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libauto.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/Versions/A/CoreUI
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/Versions/A/CoreAudio
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiskArbitration.framework/Versions/A/DiskArbitration
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MultitouchSupport.framework/Versions/A/MultitouchSupport
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/CoreServices
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PerformanceAnalysis.framework/Versions/A/PerformanceAnalysis
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/Versions/A/GenerationalStorage
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/OpenGL
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Sharing.framework/Versions/A/Sharing
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A/CoreGraphics
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Backup.framework/Versions/A/Backup
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/Versions/A/CFNetwork
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/Versions/A/SystemConfiguration
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libxar.1.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libpam.2.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libOpenScriptingUtil.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Versions/A/CarbonCore
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Metadata.framework/Versions/A/Metadata
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/OSServices
  0x000000000571c000    
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/DirectoryService.framework/Versions/A/DirectoryService
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Versions/A/DiskImages
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LoginUIKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LoginUICore.framework/Versions/A/LoginUICore
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libCoreStorage.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libcsfde.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libodfde.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/DiscRecording.framework/Versions/A/DiscRecording
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libcurl.4.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaKit.framework/Versions/A/MediaKit
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/EFILogin
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libutil.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AOSNotification.framework/Versions/A/AOSNotification
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/LDAP.framework/Versions/A/LDAP
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libsasl2.2.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libcrypto.0.9.8.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /usr/lib/libssl.0.9.8.dylib
  0x00000001200d4000    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libfontmanager.dylib
  0x000000012013b000    /Users/hangtime/Documents/games/pong-the-moba/lib/natives/liblwjgl.jnilib
  0x000000011d40c000    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_60.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libjawt.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGLProgrammability.dylib
  0x0000000000000000    /System/Library/Extensions/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/AppleIntelHD4000GraphicsGLDriver
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/Versions/A/IOAccelerator
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib
  0x0000000000000000    /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/GeForceGLDriver
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Extensions/GeForceGLDriver.bundle/Contents/MacOS/libclh.dylib
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/A/Resources/GLRendererFloat.bundle/GLRendererFloat
  0x000000000571c000    /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Versions/A/Libraries/libcldcpuengine.dylib

  VM Arguments:
  jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=lib/natives -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 13 CE.app/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
  java_command: com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain pong.Pong
  Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

  Environment Variables:
  PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
  SHELL=/bin/bash

  Signal Handlers:
  SIGSEGV: [libjvm.dylib+0x52b7b1], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000043
  SIGBUS: [libjvm.dylib+0x52b7b1], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGFPE: [libjvm.dylib+0x41e28a], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGPIPE: [libjvm.dylib+0x41e28a], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.dylib+0x41e28a], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGILL: [libjvm.dylib+0x41e28a], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGUSR1: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=0x00000000, sa_flags=0x00000002
  SIGUSR2: [libjvm.dylib+0x41dd7c], sa_mask[0]=0x00000004, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGHUP: [libjvm.dylib+0x41c00b], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGINT: [libjvm.dylib+0x41c00b], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGTERM: [libjvm.dylib+0x41c00b], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042
  SIGQUIT: [libjvm.dylib+0x41c00b], sa_mask[0]=0xfffefeff, sa_flags=0x00000042


  ---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

  OS:Bsduname:Darwin 13.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.2.0: Thu Apr 17 23:03:13 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.100.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
  rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 709, NOFILE 10240, AS infinity
  load average:4.00 3.05 3.34

  CPU:total 8 (4 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 58 stepping 9, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, tscinv

  Memory: 4k page, physical 16777216k(4194304k free)

  /proc/meminfo:


  vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.60-b09) for bsd-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_60-b19), built on May  7 2014 12:52:25 by "java_re" with gcc 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

  time: Wed Jul  2 14:09:34 2014
  elapsed time: 1 seconds
```